# When overlay menu open hide main scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found some open discussions regarding methods on how to invoke an overlay menu, and to hide the scrollbar, but I still do not have sufficient reputation points to use the simple comment and avoid using a question.

How do I hide, when the overlay page is "open", the main scrollbar (and lock the scroll for the body) and re-enable it when the overlay page is closed?

```css
 body {
          background-color: rgb(13, 199, 165);
          height: 2000px;
          overflow-y: scroll;
        }
    
        .click {
          position: fixed;
          width: 100px;
          height: 20px;
          bottom: 50px;
          left: 50px;
    
          color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
          font-family: Menlo;
          font-size: 15px;
          text-align: left;
        }
    
        .click:hover {
          color: rgb(242, 40, 27);
          cursor: pointer;
        }
    
        label {
          cursor: pointer;
        }
    
        input {
          display: none;
        }
    
        .overlay {
          position: fixed;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          background: rgb(242, 40, 27);
    
          -webkit-clip-path: inset(0% 0% 100% 0%);
          clip-path: inset(0% 0% 100% 0%);
          -webkit-transition: 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
          transition: 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
        }
    
        .overlay nav {
          position: relative;
          display: block;
          height: 100vh;
          overflow: auto;
          text-align: center;
        }
    
        .overlay ul {
          position: relative;
          display: inline-block;
          height: 50%;
          margin: 24vh auto;
          padding: 0;
    
          list-style: none;
        }
    
        .overlay ul li {
          display: block;
          height: 20%;
          min-height: 50px;
        }
    
        .overlay ul li a {
          position: relative;
          display: block;
          top: 50%;
          transform: translateY(-50%);
          color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
          text-decoration: none;
          font-family: Menlo;
          font-size: 54px;
        }
    
        .overlay ul li a:hover,
        .overlay ul li a:focus {
          color: rgb(13, 199, 165);
        }
    
        #open:checked~.overlay {
          -webkit-clip-path: inset(0% 0% 0% 0%);
          clip-path: inset(0% 0% 0% 0%);
        }
    
        .overlay nav ul {
          -webkit-transform: translateY(-400%);
          transform: translateY(-400%);
          -webkit-transition: 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
          transition: 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
        }
    
        #open:checked~.overlay nav ul {
          -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
          transform: translateY(0%);
        }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="open">
    
      <div class="click">
        <label for="open">Click here!</label>
      </div>
    
      <div class="overlay">
        <label for="open">
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </label>
      </div>
```

Comment: Your body tag has height: 2000px; so thats why you have scrollbar.You can use js to add class to your body when the button is clicked and style it.

Comment: not possible with css only...using js it can be achieved

Comment: @ЙорданРамчев Yes I know, I set the body myself with a height so that it was scrollable. Unfortunately as he says I'm a bit 'dry on js, I need an example to follow, even a link is welcome.
Thanks a lot to both in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the question I asked was simpler than I thought, but as I anticipated my knowledge of JavaScript are really limited at the moment.

However studying a bit 'I found the solution on my own, so, however trivial, I attach it to help others who are now approaching JavaScript.
This addition is based on the correction proposed by the user @sun.

Thank you all the same.

```
  <label for="open" class="open" onclick=“a()”>Enter!</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="open" class="hide">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <label for="open" class="close” onclick=“b()”>Exit!</label>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function a() {
      document.body.style.overflowY = "hidden";
    }
    function b() {
      document.body.style.overflowY = "auto";
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without JavaScript and with a different structure

```
<label for="open">Click me</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="open">
<div class="menu">...</div>
```

**Hints**

- Hide `<input type="checkbox">`.
- Choose a hover color for the label that is suitable for both background colors.
- Hide menu with `top: -100vh` and display it with `top: 0`.
- Use `vh` for font-size.

#### Example

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgb(13, 199, 165);
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
  top: -100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
}

.menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: 50vh;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.menu a {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Menlo;
  font-size: 10vh;
}

.menu a:hover,
.menu a:focus {
  color: rgb(13, 199, 165);
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.open {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  bottom: 7vh;
  left: 50px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family: Menlo;
}

.open:hover {
  color: orange;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#open:checked+.menu {
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<label for="open" class="open">Click here!</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="open" class="hide">
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I like your solution is more elegant, but unfortunately does not solve my problem. In fact if I insert in the document other div or add a "height" to the body, making it scrollable, when I activate the menu I continue to see the main scrollbar.
I try to be even clearer: when I activate the .menu I would like the scrollbar to go off, and then activate at the close of .menu.
I hope someone can help me. For now, thank you very much.